# Vale a pena utilizar os operadores binários para ganhar performance?

Tags: c++, desempenho, operadores, bitwise

Tenho as seguintes situações:

```
if (1 & 1){}
```

e

```
if (1 == 1){}
```

De acordo com o que aprendi, trabalhar com *bitwise operators* causa uma performance muito melhor no programa, com isso me surgiu algumas dúvidas:

- A performance na primeira situação realmente é melhor do que na segunda? Por quê?
- Existe situações que utilizar um operador binário causará uma performance pior?

Comment: Esse é o tipo de preocupação com performance que você **não deve** ter. É mais produtivo se preocupar com gargalos reais de performance em código real, e geralmente isso implica alterar os algoritmos utilizados. Usar um operador bitwise em vez de um `==` só vai deixar seu código menos legível e não deve ser feito a menos que você tenha certeza que vale a pena na sua situação específica.

Comment: discordo do amigo acima, primeiro que o teor da pergunta e sobre performace nao sobre gargalos, performace dos codigos afetam sim em tempo de respostas, não que seja algo significante, mais na minha opinião vale mais performace do que codigo bunito. so pra constar nao sou profissional da area por tanto posso estar falando merda

Comment: @ArsomNolasco Meu comentário tem a ver com o que o Maniero respondeu agora há pouco. Questões de performance não devem ser tratadas de maneira abstrata, depende do contexto específico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em muitos casos sim, em muitos não. Em geral a recomendação é não usá-los até que a performance não esteja boa o suficiente ou que só a manipulação seja adequada para a semântica desejada, até porque os compiladores atuais costumam trocar a operação aritmética ou relacional pela manipulação de bits, sempre que for vantajoso. Mas ele não resolve todos os casos da melhor forma. A maioria resolve melhor que o programador.

Em exemplos artificiais assim, [o código na verdade será reduzido a nada](https://godbolt.org/g/GvNrhu). Só fica o *header* e *footer* da função (em alguns casos nem isso):

[image: Header/footer de função]

Só testando na situação específica na implementação específica, na arquitetura específica, para ver se ficar mais rápido ou não.

É útil fazer isso quando precisa da performance e sabe que o compilador não está otimizando adequadamente.

Também é útil se a semântica for de manipulação de números em mais baixo nível, já que a intenção é mesmo mexer com bits e não um número de alto nível.

Em alguns casos o processador pode otimizar a execução, até mesmo além desta operação, dependendo da instrução usada no código, mas só o compilador sabe que instrução ele usou.

Então também vai um pouco do gosto na maioria dos casos.

Se usar errado tudo pode ser pior.

Nem falei da diferença entre processadores. E não é só família, varia até de acordo com o modelo.

Então depende, não dá para responder em algo que sequer tem uma resposta definitiva.

- [Como o GCC gera o código nas condições padrões](https://godbolt.org/g/EcviwN).
- [Como o MSVC gera o código nas condições padrões](https://godbolt.org/g/abAHVG).
- [Como o ICC gera o código nas condições padrões](https://godbolt.org/g/hezJTG).
- [Como o Clang gera o código nas condições padrões](https://godbolt.org/g/ZrhvnS).
- [Como o GCC no ARM gera o código nas condições padrões](https://godbolt.org/g/fY6P5h).

O fato de gerar códigos diferentes não quer dizer que um é mais rápido do que o outro já que cada instrução tem um tempo de execução diferente e depende do contexto geral e do ambiente de execução. É possível medir, mas dá trabalho. A versão do compilador e configurações podem mudar o código gerado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Senti falta do "Por quê?", poderia explica-lo?

Comment: @Francisco editei para tentar "responder"

Comment: [PGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) (Profile Guided Optimization) também pode alterar o branch pra uma instrução sem branches caso o primeiro for verificado como lento!